# Parse a log file using java.regex.Matcher

Tags: java

I am learning Java programming. I have a Cisco log:

```
String logLine="Jul 15 21:12:41 router_provider_pe2 57: *Jul 15 21:12:26.223: %LDP-5-NBRCHG: LDP Neighbor 10.1.1.34:0 (3) is UP";
```

I am trying this regular expression:

```
String logPattern = "([\\w]+\\s[\\d]+\\s[\\d:]+) (\\d+:) ([*\\w]+\\s[\\d]+\\s[\\d:]+:) (\\w.+)";
```

But it is not fine. Could you help me?

Comment: I want cut the message: Date, host, timestamp, facility, severity, mnemonic and message

Comment: Every time I see a question like this I have to ask: Is it a _requirement_ that you use a `Matcher`?  Way too often, questioners here assume that they have to use a regex--or maybe they just want to use regexes because regexes are cool or something--but often they're not the best approach.  In your case, have you considered `split()`?

Comment: I had consider split. It is more code.

Comment: "More code" is not a problem to be avoided.  I've seen too many cases where someone tried to solve something with an insanely complicated regex.  The match took just one statement, but that one statement was totally incomprehensible to readers.  (Your regex isn't nearly that bad, by the way.  I'm talking about cases that are _much_ worse.)  Simple and understandable code is a more important goal than "less code".

Answer (score 0):

Your string:

```
"Jul 15 21:12:41 router_provider_pe2 57: *Jul 15 21:12:26.223: %LDP-5-NBRCHG: LDP Neighbor 10.1.1.34:0 (3) is UP"
```

Your pattern:

```
 "([\w]+\s[\d]+\s[\d:]+) (\d+:) ([*\w]+\s[\d]+\s[\d:]+:) (\w.+)"
```

The part of the pattern in the first set of parentheses matches `Jul 15 21:12:41`.  The pattern expects this to be followed by a space, and then by at least one digit.  But the string at this point contains a space and the letter `r`, which is not a digit.  Therefore, there is no match.